# Finance in the Torah

Tags: sources-mekorot, money

Knowing that Finance is an integral part of one's daily life, is the idea of how one should budget mentioned in the Torah Sh'beksav or Torah Sh'baal Peh?

Comment: That's too broad... many rules have something to do with economics.

Comment: How about investment advise? Bava Metzia 42a 'And Rebbe Yitzchak said: A person should always have his money at hand, as it is written (Deuteronomy 14:?) "And bind the money in your hand". And Rebbe Yitzchak said, A person should always divide his money into three: one third in land, one third in commerce, and one third at hand.'

Comment: https://faithandpubliclife.com/joseph-and-the-famine-does-god-favor-economic-centralization/

Comment: Don't go into the upper millstone business because nobody will be allowed to accept your collateral.